# overlapping colors in ggplot geom_point

Tags: r, ggplot2, alpha, geom-point

I was looking to plot some points colored following 2 variables and overly colors.
thanks to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19778612/change-color-for-two-geom-point-in-ggplot2), I have a close result like below

```r
library(ggplot2)
data=data.frame(x=1:4,y=1:4,var1=c(1,0,0,1),var2=c(0,1,NA,1))
ggplot(data,aes(x,y))+
  geom_point(aes(color=as.factor(var1)),alpha=0.5,size=3)+
  geom_point(aes(colour=as.factor(var2)),alpha=0.5,size=1)
```

[image]

my aim is to color var1 with grey/yellow 0/1 var2 in grey/blue 0/1 and have a green overlap (same size)

<sup>Created on 2024-01-21 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: your plot doesn't seems to match the data. Where are 2,3,4 from?

Comment: @Jinjin point1(x=1,y=1) point2 (x=2,y=2) and so on ..

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
library(tidyverse)

data_long <- data %>% 
  pivot_longer(c(var1, var2)) %>% 
  mutate(color = case_when(
    name == "var1" & value == 1 ~ "yellow",
    name == "var2" & value == 1 ~ "blue",
    .default = "grey")
    )

ggplot(data_long, aes(x, y, color = color))+
  geom_point(data = data_long %>% 
               filter(name == "var1"), alpha = 0.5, size = 9) +
  geom_point(data = data_long %>% 
               filter(name == "var2"), alpha = 0.9, size = 3) +
  scale_color_identity(guide = 'legend')
```

[image]